# Rendering on query parameter based on date in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am looking for best solution for page rendering based on "date query string" using **getStaticPaths** and **getStaticProps**.

I have just on input from the user on the index page, I don't have a list with possible dates/routes.

```
<DatePicker onChange={(date) => router.push('/tasks/daily/' + date}/>
```

which pulls the data from `/api/reports/daily?day=${date}` route in the **tasks/[id].js** page.

Is there any solution on SSR or ISR render if I don't know my paths previously, or I should stick just to client-side rendering using useEffect Hook.